# Trying to communicate with Heatmiser neoHub using provided API, JSON over TCP and C#

Tags: c#, json, tcp

I'm trying to write a simple program to communicate with a Heatmiser neoHub which should enable fetching and setting of a variety of information regarding my heating system.

According to Heatmiser API documentation I should use JSON over TCP to the neoHub's port 4242, I think my sending code is working but I'm getting no response.

At the moment I have a small .Net Core 2.2 console app which encodes a JSON command to an array of bytes and sends this to the TCP socket connected to the neoHub, I then wait for a response from the neoHub.

My first attempts would have parsed the return JSON and had no timeout on the connection and waited for several minutes before I would kill the app with no response.  The current version has been simplified further to just output any response unparsed JSON to the console and only waits 10 seconds but I still get no response.

```
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;

namespace NeoHub
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            socket.Connect("192.168.0.204", 4242);
            socket.ReceiveTimeout = 10000;

            Console.WriteLine("connected...");
            string jsonData = "{\"GET_LIVE_DATA\":0}";

            byte[] sendData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonData);
            byte[] readData = new byte[1024 * 4];

            try
            {
                int sendBytes = socket.Send(sendData);
                Console.WriteLine("sent {0}...", sendBytes);

                int readBytes = socket.Receive(readData);
                Console.WriteLine("receive {0}...", readBytes);
                Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(readData));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

The result of a {"GET_LIVE_DATA":0} should be a JSON file similar to below  (I've truncated the example output).

```
{
"CLOSE_DELAY": 0,
"COOL_INPUT": false,
"GLOBAL_SYSTEM_TYPE": "HeatOnly",
"HOLIDAY_END": 0,
"HUB_AWAY": false,
"HUB_HOLIDAY": false,
"HUB_TIME": 1518613752,
"OPEN_DELAY": 0,
"TIMESTAMP_DEVICE_LISTS": 1518607836,
"TIMESTAMP_ENGINEERS": 1518607837,
"TIMESTAMP_PROFILE_0": 1518607836,
"TIMESTAMP_PROFILE_COMFORT_LEVELS": 1518604883,
"TIMESTAMP_PROFILE_TIMERS": 1518600089,
"TIMESTAMP_PROFILE_TIMERS_0": 1518607918,
"TIMESTAMP_SYSTEM": 1518607836
}
```

Comment: I'm looking to play around with the API myself. Do you have a link to the documentation? Any other relevant docs/guides welcome!

Comment: I'm not sure if this is still the latest but it was sent from Heatmiser's Support Team after an email conversation with them https://faq.heatmiser.com/attachments/token/AP9T71kc80Jwa3862LJoygl9V/?name=Neohub+Api+For+systems+developers+rev+2.601.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to solve my own problem by looking through the Python solution on GitHub https://github.com/RJ/heatmiser-neohub.py.

The small and crucial addition is an end of line:

```
string jsonData = "{\"GET_LIVE_DATA\":0}";
```

needs to be

```
string jsonData = "{\"GET_LIVE_DATA\":0}" + "\0\r";
```